# Como puedo utilizar estilos definidos en de app.component.scss en todos los componentes - app ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic, botón, scss

Estoy trabajando con ionic / angular, donde tengo componentes que comparten estilos  css comunes, por ejemplo en el caso de los botones ( o ) tienen todos el mismo estilo.
Entonces agregué la clase en el **app.component.scss**  de la aplicación y en cada componente específico como por ejemplo el de login (que tiene su propio login.scss) quiero aplicar esa clase al botón de Ingresar. **Pero no lo toma, no entiendo como resolverlo**

**En app.component.scss creé**

```
  .btnIngresar{
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1.33em;
    width: 22em;
    color:white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 22em;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.875rem 1rem;
    border-radius: 0.66em;
  }
```

En el html del componente de login agrego esta clase (Que está en app.component.scss) al botón de ingresar. **No toma el estilo de la clase**

**login.html**

`<button class="btnIngresar"> Aceptar </button`>

Si lo agrego en login.page.scss funciona. Pero como este estilo de boton va a ser utilizado en cada componente de la aplicación quiero dejarlo genérico y no tener que repetir el mismo código en cada scss de cada componente de esta aplicación.

Tengo que usar el mismo estilo para los formularios y cada página que contenga un boton de acción habilitada.

***¿Ideas? ¿Sugerencias de como resolverlo sin tener que repetir el mismo codigo en cada hoja de estilo de cada componente?***

Comment: Yo opte por crear un archivo components.scss con los estilos globales y un archivo especifico de acuerdo a la instancia; en login.scss usaria la regla @import "nombredearchivo" para usar los estilos de esa hoja y a partir de hay crear los específicos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! No sabía que se podia importar. O sea que podría hacer un @import del app.component.scss en login?